# Why does our dog pee/poop when we aren't home?

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, toilet-training, containment

Our dog is almost 9 years old. She never pees or poops in the house while we're present, she only does it when we're gone.

We recently had a similar problem that we were able to solve. Our dog used to pee/poop in the living room at night after we'd go to bed and closed the door. If we left the door open, she'd jump in bed with us and she wouldn't pee or poop all night. This showed us that the issue was behavioral, not that she couldn't hold it in overnight. We ultimately solved this problem by getting a kennel and having her sleep in there overnight and she hasn't peed or pooped overnight since.

That worked for overnight, but we don't want to have to lock her in her kennel during the day when we're gone at work. What other option do we have to stop her from peeing/pooping in the house while we're gone?

It's worth noting that our dog is not spayed.

Comment: Separation anxiety perhaps.  Do you know how she reacts to being left? Is it stressful?

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is a combination of separation anxiety and a behavior issue.  You should contact your vet and get their opinion and to get a blood workup done before doing too much, as it may be a medical problem.  But you should not yell or rub it's nose in it, that just feeds the anxiety.  Ask your vet if your dog needs medication (puppy valium or prozac) to help with the issue, and then find out if she could recommend a puppy behaviorist.  You can download a music cd. to help calm it down while your gone.  Even if your not seeing the accidents going on, they are just looking for the attention, good or bad.   I have the same issue and as mad as I get I can't yell at them.  I just say bad puppies in a firm voice (but I dont yell) and clean the mess up.  They know what they did is wrong and once I'm done I give them plenty of love and attention.  I have found the music has helped alot (not t.v. or radio) and I'll tell them I'll be right back as I'm walking out the door (no eye contact).  They are smarter than you think and will catch on fast.  But make sure you check with a vet and make sure it's not a medical condition.  (I don't believe in crating an animal unless it's an emergency or for the welfare of others)